# c program tries of games repeated when looping the program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    int guess = 0;
    int response = 1;
    int tries = 0;
    srand(time(0));

    while (response == 1)
    {
        printf("Please type your first guess.\n");
        num = rand() % 1000 + 1;
        while (guess != num)
        {
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            tries = tries + 1;
            if (guess == num)
            {
                printf("good job\n");
            }
            else if (guess > num)
            {
                printf("too high, try again\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("too low, try again\n");
            }
        }
        printf("Guess Taken = %d\n", tries);
        printf ("Would you like to play again? \n");
        printf("Please type ( 1=yes, 2=no ) ");
        scanf ("%d", &response);


    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of "Guess Taken" of the second time to run the program equal to the sum of first and second time. How to solve the problem?

For example,

1st: 9 tries

2nd: 8 tries

The output of the program showed 17 tries instead of 8 tries.

Comment: you never reset `tries` and keep adding to it.  You probably want to set it to zero at the top of your outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  printf("I have a number between 1 and 1000.\n" 
>      "Can you guess my number?\n" 
>      "Please type your first guess.\n");
> num = rand() % 1000 + 1; 
> while(guess != num)
> ```

Set `tries` to `0` before entering the `while`-loop:

```
num = rand() % 1000 + 1;
tries = 0;
while(guess != num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset the variable `tries` to zero after each game. If you put `tries = 0;` immediately after the first while loop it should work.